# Missing tool in Deep Learning: data augmentation with geometrical landmarks

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

**Data augmentation** can easily be achieved using ad hoc modules in e.g. TensorFlow. This works perfectly for classification problems, however when the objective of the network is the **prediction of a geometrical feature**, e.g. a landmark, a problem arises. As the image is modified, e.g. flipped, or distorted, **the corresponding labels also need to be adapted**.

1 - Is there **any tool to do this**? I am sure that this is a common problem.

2 - Would it be useful to create a data augmentation script for neural networks that predict geometrical features?

I want to understand if I need to code all of this by myself or if I am missing something that already exists. If I need to do it and it could be useful I would just create an open source thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use imgaug library https://github.com/aleju/imgaug

An example of augmentation for key points using imgaug you can find here https://github.com/aleju/imgaug#example-augment-images-and-keypoints

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to be what I was looking for. Great that it also works for bounding boxes and other types of annotations. :)